# Android Google maps V2 Auth Errror with Correct Parameters

Tags: android, google-maps, certificate

I followed all auth steps and generated with succes the file debug.keystore, however I get this auth error in my android "hello world" google maps v2 app.

Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.testxml, API Key: **AIzaSyBznd-xKvRfT8Gfsp_1c9n2ZYbsqcRgkAI**, Certificate Fingerprint: **D279CD725FF15AD9376F7360425CA81A703E61F6**

Google Api Console Text: 
API key:
**AIzaSyBznd-xKvRfT8Gfsp_1c9n2ZYbsqcRgkAI**
Android apps:
**D2:79:CD:72:5F:F1:5A:D9:37:6F:73:60:42:5C:A8:1A:70:3E:61:F6**;com.example.testxml
Activated on:   Nov 10, 2013 1:49 PM

Am I missing something or I just have to wait? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uninstall the app from your device and then install it again normally via IDE.